# Is it possible to disable global/user hot keys in ConEmu for specified applications?

Tags: conemu

In my FAR's user menu I have the following entry:

```
emacs -nw -new_console
```

When I press C-v in emacs it inserts text because conemu hot key is fired first. Can I tell conemu not to use its hot keys when some particular application is run? Or alternatively can I run a new application in a ConEmu tab but as it was run as a standalone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, per-app hotkeys are not supported.

Regardless of the fact the mentioned hotkey is not "global"

Comment: Yes, I updated question subject after. As I noticed later Ctrl+C's type was User.

Comment: I've checked emacs in cygwin. And C-v works fine there. Why is Ctrl+V not caught by Conemu in cygwin's emacs?
I start cygwin in a tab with this command:
**C:\App\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i C:\App\cygwin\Cygwin-Terminal.ico - -new_console**

Comment: Read docs: http://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html

Comment: Things are more clear now. But could you advise when you run application in a terminal (use Conemu as just a container) and when as console applications?
For example is it better to run cygwin using mintty or to run directly bash.exe from a batch file?
Is it better to run windows version of emacs/vim directly, in cygwin or in some other terminal?

Comment: Personally I always prefer console version. Don't like to run ChildGui. But I know many users running mintty. All pros and cons are described in docs. Your choice...